# Laravel orm database query inside model function

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-5, eloquent

I am new in Laravel. I want to make some custom functions in models which is related to database query.

```
Class A Extends Controller{
  public function view(){
    B::get_user();
  }
}

Class B Extends Model{
  protected $table = "user";

  public function get_user(){
    //Here is my database query
  }
}
```

How can I use database query in get_user() function? I know this method:

```
B::table('user')->get();
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can define query [`scopes`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes) for adding the query on the model as:

```
public function scopeUser($query)
{
    return $query->where('some_field', 'some_value');
}
```

Then you can use it in you controller as:

```
B::user()->get();
```

[Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent#local-scopes)